# Trouble with Java Hangman game

Tags: java

I made an algorithm for my java hang man game that adds the users guess to an array that matches the guess to a letter in the word. If the answer is correct it adds the letter to arraylist guesses in the same spot as it is in the word. Once the method is done  For some reason the answer always returns incorrect.

```
  public class HangMan
{
   public final int GAME=9;
public void Hangman()
{
words();
}
String nerd="";
public void words()
{
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Random randomgenerator =new Random();
int random = randomgenerator.nextInt(4);
String myArray[]={"albatross","cat","mitosis","computer","coding"};
nerd=myArray[random];
//get length of word
int length=nerd.length();

       //create hangman
       System.out.println(" ------");
       System.out.println(" |");
       System.out.println(" |");
       System.out.println(" |");
       System.out.println(" |");
       System.out.println("____");
       System.out.println("Guess a letter!"); 



       //create dashes
       for(int z=0;z<length;z++)
       {
         System.out.print("_");
       }
    }




public void check()
{   

ArrayList<String>guesses=new ArrayList<String>();
  //Inputs a scanner
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // pre condition:if player guess equals a char in nerd 

           String guess1=in.nextLine();
           char guess=guess1.charAt(0);
           for(int i=0;i<nerd.length();i++)
           {

           }
              if(guess==nerd.charAt(z))
              {


                 System.out.println("Correct");
                 System.out.println("Your word so far");
                 System.out.print(guesses);
                  guesses.set(z, guess+"");
                 System.out.println("You have");
                 System.out.print(nerd.length()-z);
                 System.out.print("guesses left");

              }



           //pre condition: if the guess is wrong
           else
           { 
           System.out.println("Wrong");
           System.out.println("Your word so far");
           System.out.print(guesses);
           System.out.println("You have");
           System.out.print(nerd.length()-z);
           System.out.print("guesses left");

           }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over `i` but you are trying to compare `guess` against a character at index `z`. I don't think your code is formatted entirely correctly either but this is certainly a problem.

Btw you might want to make use of the String method `contains()` instead of using your loop

Comment: When using the .contains() how would I add the input to a specific position in my guesses array.   Right now I have this code, but if I remove my for loop I can't set the guess to a specific position.                                                                                          guesses.set(i, guess+"");

Comment: Using contains or not won't solve your problem, just potentially improve your code. You're right in that you will need the index at some point too. What about my main comment about the iteration?